# Enable "customization" using constants in VBA (Excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I want to enable some kind of user customization in my VBA Excel tool. Therefore i try to use constants in the beginning of the code. For most use cases that works already fine but for the following lines of code i did not find any solution yet.

```
Set DatenBereich = .Range("A4:V" & _
                .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
```

What I am looking for is a way to replace "A4:V" by two constants called for example STARTCELL and ENDCOLUMN.

Do you guys have any idea how I can easily realize that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why doesn't this work? `STARTCELL = "A4" : ENDCOLUMN = "V" : Set DatenBereich = .Range(STARTCELL & ":" & ENDCOLUMN & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unknown to me as to why you would want a [constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/declaring-constants) for this purpose, but it would look something like this:

```
Sub test()

    Const STARTCELL$ = "A4"
    Const ENDCOLUMN$ = "V"

    '...

    Set DatenBereich = .Range(STARTCELL & ":" & ENDCOLUMN & _
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)

End Sub
```

But as you may (or may not) be aware, constants do not change value upon runtime.

You can include the cell separator with the `ENDCOLUMN` if you so choose:

```
Sub test()

    Const STARTCELL As String = "A4"
    Const ENDCOLUMN As String = ":V"

    '...

    Set DatenBereich = .Range(STARTCELL & ENDCOLUMN & _
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row)

End Sub
```